# Correct way to block read operations until an external event?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I am working on a devices driver for a data acquisition system. There is a pci device that provides input and output data at the same time at regular intervals. And then the linux mod manages the data in circular buffers that are read and written to through file operations.

The data throughput of the system is relatively low it receives just over 750,000 bytes/second and transmits just over 150,000 bytes per second.

There is a small user space utility that writes and reads data in a loop for testing purposes.

Here is a section of the driver code (All the code related to the circular buffers has been omitted for simplicity sake. PCI device initialization is taken care of elsewhere and pci_interupt not the real entry point for the interrupt handler)

```
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/wait.h>
static DECLARE_WAIT_QUEUE_HEAD(wq_head);
static ssize_t read(struct file *filp, char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos)
{
    DECLARE_WAITQUEUE(wq, current);
    if(count == 0)
        return 0;
    add_wait_queue(&wq_head, &wq);
    do
    {
        set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
        if(/*There is any data in the receive buffer*/)
        {
            /*Copy Data from the receive buffer into user space*/
            break;
        }
        schedule();
    } while(1);
    set_current_state(TASK_RUNNING);
    remove_wait_queue(&wq_head, &wq);
    return count;
}
static ssize_t write(struct file *filp, const char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos) {
    /* Copy data from userspace into the transmit buffer*/
}
/* This procedure get's called in real time roughly once every 5 milliseconds, 
It writes 4k to the receiving buffer and reads 1k from the transmit buffer*/
static void pci_interrupt() {
    /*Copy data from PCI dma buffer to receiving buffer*/
    if(/*There is enough data in the transmit buffer to fill the PCI dma buffer*/) {
        /*Copy from the transmit buffer to the PCI device*/
    } else {
        /*Copy zero's to the PCI device*/
        printk(KERN_ALERT DEVICE_NAME ": Data Underflow. Writing 0's'");
    }
    wake_up_interruptible(&wq_head);
}
```

The above code works well for long periods of time however every 12-18 hours there is a data underflow error. Resulting in zeros being written.

My first thought is that due to the userspace application not being truly real-time the time delay between it's read and write operations occasionally got too large causing the failure. However I tried changing the size of the reads and writes in userspace and changing the niceness of the userspace application this had no effect on the frequency of the error.

Do to the error's nature I believe there is some form of race condition in the three methods above. I am not sure how linux kernel wait queues work.

Is there a decent alternative to the above method for blocking reads or is there something else that is wrong the could cause this behavior.

System Information:

Linux Version: Ubuntu 16.10

Linux Kernel: linux-4.8.0-lowlatency

Chipset: Intel Celeron N3150/N3160 Quad Core 2.08 GHz SoC

**TL;DR:** The above code hits underflow errors every 12-18 hours is there a better way to do blocking IO or some race condition in the code.

Answer (score 0):

One standard way used in linux can also be used in your case.

**User space** test program:
 1. open file in blocking mode (default in linux until you specify NONBLOCK flag)
 2. call select() to block on file descriptor.

**Kernel driver**:
 1. Register interrupt handler which gets invoked whenever there is data available
 2. Handler take lock to protect common buffer between reads/writes and transfer of data
Take a look at these links for source code from ldd3 book [test](https://github.com/martinezjavier/ldd3/blob/master/misc-progs/polltest.c) and [driver](https://github.com/martinezjavier/ldd3/blob/master/snull/snull.c).